# Interesting Graph Problem?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, connectedness

I am given an undirected connected graph of $N$ vertices and $M$ edges. I need to make this undirected graph directed by directing edges.I need to check if it's possible to make a directed graph such that indegree of all vertices of new directed graph is even.

I could only think that if the edges of graph is odd, it's impossible to make such directed graph. I worked on this problem, but couldn't think more.

Constraints :$- 1 \leq N \leq 10^5$ and $1 \leq M \leq 10^5$

Example :- 
$N = 4$
$M = 4$
Edges are $(1,2), (1,3), (2,4)$ and $(3,4)$
Answer :- Possible
We can make a directed graph, $1\rightarrow2$, $1\rightarrow3$, $4\rightarrow2$ and $4\rightarrow 3$. Note that indegree of all vertices is even.

Answer (score 1):

> if the edges of graph is odd, it's impossible to make such directed graph

It remains to prove that if the number of edges is even then we can direct them providing in-degree of each vertex is even. Assume to the contrary, that there exists a direction of edges of the graph with minimal and non-zero number of vertices of odd in-degree.  Since the sum of in-degrees of all vertices of the graph equals to the number of edges, which is even, there are at least two vertices $v$ and $u$ of odd in-degree each. Since the graph is connected, there is a (shortest)  path from $v$ to $u$. When we redirect each edge of this path, we change the parity of in-degree of $v$ and $u$, but don’t change the parity of in-degree of all other vertices of the graph. Thus we decreased a number of vertices of odd in-degree, a contradiction.